# Try and Except Block for User Input - Accounting for multiple scenarios

Tags: python

I am currently creating a Python program that requires a user to input an amount.

My code is below:

```
while True:
    try:
        integer_user = int(input('Please enter your amount:'))
        if integer_user > 1000 and integer_user < self.owner.getValue():
            break
    except ValueError:
        print(f'Please enter a positive integer as your amount!')
```

The issue is, that I want to present two different error messages for the user.

If the user puts in a value that is greater than the owner value, I want to tell them, you cannot enter an amount greater than the owner value.

If the user (for example) writes a string, I want to tell them, Please enter a positive integer as your amount.

I am struggling to account for both scenarios. I can only account for the latter and not the former. Can anyone provide insight?

Comment: Trace through your code in the case where `integer_user` is a valid (but excessively large) integer. Are there any places in the control flow that are *only* reached in this case? That's where your other error message should go.

Comment: Print the error message after `break`.

Answer (score 0):

If the condition isn't true, you'll continue executing after the `break`. So put the error message there.

```
while True:
    try:
        integer_user = int(input('Please enter your amount:'))
        if 1000 < integer_user < self.owner.getValue():
            break
        print(f"Your amount must be between 1000 and {self.owner.getValue()}")
    except ValueError:
        print(f'Please enter an integer as your amount!')
```